# ASP.NET - MvcMailer - Email Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mailer, mvcmailer

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with MVCMailer, I tried to send e-mails with a email certificate from COMODO to keep server messages secure:

http://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/free-email-certificate.php

Does anyone know if is possible to add a email certificate using  MVCMailer?